# How to specify multiple conditions in a do-until loop in Ansible

Tags: python, yaml, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am making a REST call and want to check my request to be completed before going on. In the response, I either got a "PENDING" or "IN_PROGRESS" as request_status. I want to wait until I get either a "COMPLETED" or "FAILED". For this purpose, I want to wait while getting a "PENDING" or "IN_PROGRESS"

I tried lots of variations but could not succeeded and the last try was as below:

```
  - name: Wait for the cluster deployment (this will take a while)
    uri:
      url: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/{{ cluster_name }}/requests/1
      method: GET
      user: admin
      password: admin
      HEADER_X-Requested-By: Ansible
      force_basic_auth: yes
      status_code: 200, 201, 202
      return_content: yes
    register: response
    until: "'{{ (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'PENDING' AND '{{ (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'IN_PROGRESS'"
    retries: 3
    delay: 5
```

And the error is:

> "The conditional check ''{{ (response.content
>   | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'PENDING' AND '{{
>   (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' !=
>   'IN_PROGRESS'' failed. The error was: template error while templating
>   string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'AND'. String: {%
>   if 'COMPLETED' != 'PENDING' AND 'COMPLETED' != 'IN_PROGRESS' %} True
>   {% else %} False {% endif %}"

So, my question is how can I specify multiple conditions in a do-until loop in Ansible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok found the problem.

Changing "AND" to "and" worked.

> until: "'{{ (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}'
>   != 'PENDING' **and** '{{ (response.content |
>   from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'IN_PROGRESS'"

Comment: when you are using Jinja, you are actually executing python.  the proper python vernacular for the `and` logic, is literally `and`, not `AND`.  glad you figured it out. just though you should know ;)

Comment: Can we create an infinite loop without `do-until` loop for the same problem above? say loop will be infinitely check this condition `"'{{ (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'PENDING' and '{{ (response.content | from_json).Requests.request_status }}' != 'IN_PROGRESS'"`.Then on condition met it will come out from the loop. Kindly advice me for the same.

Comment: how annoying. The error messages are treasurehunts anyways in Ansible.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible (at least with Ansible 2.8.3) to pass arrays to `until`:

```
- shell: "echo OK"
  until:
    - 1 == 1
    - "'no'.replace('no', 'yes') == 'yes'"
```

In this case array items are implicitly "joined" with `and`