# Ansible - How to 'wait_for' DNS to be available or How using lookup('dig') with 'until'

Tags: ansible, dig

I made something that is working but I look for something more 'elegant' ;)

```yaml
- name: Wait for DNS propagation
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: host "{{ vm_fqdn }}"
  register: dns_result
  until: dns_result.rc == 0
  retries: 30
  delay: 10
```

But previously I tried with a `lookup` and the `community.general.dig`

```yaml
- name: Wait for DNS propagation
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    dns_result: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', vm_fqdn)}}"
  until: dns_result == vm_ip
  retries: 30
  delay: 10
```

Unfortunately, even I added a `register` I couldn't get the `dns_result` variable updated after multiple tries. It's like the `lookup` happens only once on the first iteration, but is not 're-triggered' on the next try. So maybe it is the behavior of `lookup` or something else, but I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the lookup at the wrong point. It should be directly in the `until`, so that it is evaluated each time.

```yaml
- name: Wait for DNS propagation
  debug:
    msg: waiting
  until: lookup('community.general.dig', vm_fqdn) == vm_ip
  retries: 30
  delay: 10
```

Comment: That is perfect ! I just tested it and it react exactly as expected - Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

> *I couldn't get the `dns_result` variable updated after multiple tries ... but is not 're-triggered' on the next try.*

Right, that is the expected behavior for your given example.

> *It's like the `lookup` happens only once on the first iteration*

But this caused by the way variables becomes registered and handled internally. For the `retries` loop run the variable content for `until` condition will stay at the initial value since it is set (registered) at "compile time" and not "re-set during run time".

The following example will show the behavior.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    RETRIES: [1, 2, 3]

  tasks:

  - name: Set Facts in loop
    set_fact:
      RESULT: "{{ ansible_loop.index }}"
    # Inner loop
    until: RESULT == '3'
    retries: 3
    delay: 1
    # Outer loop
    loop: "{{ RETRIES }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ item }}"
```

As one can see from the result output, the `retries` behaves like an loop for the inner object, which is a single outer loop state here.

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (1 retries left).

TASK [Set Facts in loop] *****************************
failed: [localhost] (item=1) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    RESULT: '1'
...
  ansible_loop_var: item
  attempts: 3
  item: 1
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set Facts in loop (1 retries left).
failed: [localhost] (item=2) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    RESULT: '2'
...
  ansible_loop_var: item
  attempts: 3
  item: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
```

To summarize, the construct `set_fact` - `lookup('dig')` - `retries` - `until` can't work unless the initial condition is already `true`. This is shown in the example run #3.

**Documentation**

- [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met)

  > *When you run a task with `until` and register the result as a variable, the registered variable will include a key called “attempts”, which records the number of the retries for the task.*

**Further Q&A**

- [How to specify multiple conditions in a do until loop in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874322/)

---

**Possible Solutions**

You may

- either stay with you first approach
- try something with the [`wait_for` module – Waits for a condition before continuing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) since according [Parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-host) `host:` there is the option for

  > *A resolvable hostname or IP address to wait for.*

  ```yaml
  - name: Wait for host
    wait_for:
      host: test.example.com
      port: 22
      timeout: 5
    register: result
  ```

  but you will need a port to check for at least.
- or use the [here proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502769/6771046) from flowerysong (recommended)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations  - I understand better now how lookup and until are working.
I will use @Zeitounator solution because I'm doing this dns check before adding the machine in the inventory, So I can't use `wait_for` at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and most ansible-native approach I use is:

```yaml
- name: Getting ready to start
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:   
    - name: Wait for DNS propagation
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: not inventory_hostname is ansible.utils.resolvable
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Waiting...
      until: inventory_hostname is ansible.utils.resolvable
      retries: 900
      delay: 10
```

Here is the bonus also that it will not be printing "Waiting..." for the FQDNs which are already resolvalble.

Comment: Thanks for your add, I will try with a different variable, because when I use that 'loop', the VM is not in the inventory yet.